# What is the name of this window related toolbar?

Tags: windows-7

What is the name for this button combo, that allows you to snap a window to a certain monitor, or expand the window across all monitors?

I've been trying to figure out the name of it, and how to disable it.

[image]

Comment: Not sure of the specific name, but they are just custom window buttons.  Do you have a 3rd party multiple monitor app? Similar to [UltraMon](https://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/tour/windows.asp).  Right-click on taskbar and see if you have something like "multiple monitor support" and see if there are options that control this (like [DisplayFusion](https://www.displayfusion.com/Discussions/View/disable-titlebar-button/?ID=2af6330f-9c01-4710-8395-1efaced8d98e) ).

Comment: @BlueGI Bingo! UltraMon is what it was. I've had it for so long, I forgot about checking that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to BlueGl, he pointed out to check 3rd party applications, which I forgot about.

The buttons were able to be disabled in UltraMon.

To disable the buttons, right click on the UltraMon icon in the notification area, and select options.

It will open a window, and then select the *Buttons and Menu Commands* tab. From there in the button section, uncheck *add Move Window button* and *add Maximize Desktop button*

[image]